# JQuery functions not working in Android App development

Tags: android, jquery

I may be going about this completely the wrong way, but I'm attempting to migrate a web-based application to an Android application with as minimal changes as possible.

I have set up my Android application to populate from an HTML page, which works fine in my original basic example.

However, when I try to add any JQuery functions, these fail.

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('outside doc ready');
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert('inside JQuery');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>Some text</body>

</html>
```

Rendered in a browser, I get both the alert messages.
Rendered through the Android App on my Samsung Galaxy S3, I simply get the first 'outside doc ready' alert.
I have previously included a JQuery Mobile link, but it made no difference and my understanding is that it is more a UI function set anyway.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If any further information is required, please let me know and I'll edit the question.

Comment: In many application if javascript alerts are called more than once then some times browser tells you that "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" then if you press ok then, No alert will appear next time

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  However, if I remove the $(document).ready wrapper, and just leave the second alert, then it successfully fires in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load jQuery externally, you have to add the internet permission to the Android Manifest.

Comment: Hi.  I added the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to the Android Manifest XML, and can confirm it does work.  Plus 1 and approved answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this working.

For reasons I hope someone can explain, JQuery was not being loaded.  I manually saved the JQuery library and added it into the 'assets' folder alongside the test html page.
I then simply modified the include line...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And the page started working.

I suspect there are some security limitations at play here, as including 3rd party or external Javascript files to an application running in a local context is probably a bit dodgy.

If you took the time to read, thank you.

Comment: You may not have had internet connection in your mobile/AVD

Comment: The phone definitely has an internet connection.  I guess it could take a while to load and therefore not be in memory by the time the functions are called?